# Artifact com.oracle.toplink:toplink:jar:10.1.3 not found

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, toplink, toplink-essentials

I am trying to create a spring 4 project from scratch and maven is unable to resolve the dependency of `com.oracle.toplink:toplink:jar:10.1.3`

The following are the repositories that I have set in the `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo2.maven.org</id>
        <name>repo2.maveng.org</name>
        <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>repo1.maven.org</id>
        <name>repo1.maven.org</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <name>java.net</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.spring.io</id>
        <name>repo.spring.io-releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Questions:

- Which repo should I add to make sure maven resolves this dependency?
- Usually, how does one know which repo has a particular artifact belong to?
- The error message I see is below. Does this error mean Maven did not try looking up for it in other repositories mentioned?

  Could not find artifact com.oracle.toplink:toplink:jar:10.1.3 in repo2.maven.org (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

The is Oracle toplink - toplink-10.1.3 in maven's Central repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. So you just only need to add the dependency in pom.xml, not the repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.toplink</groupId>
    <artifactId>toplink</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Source:

1. http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/com.oracle.toplink/toplink/10.1.3
2. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.toplink/toplink/10.1.3

Comment: Well, I guess that one of the spring related dependency in turn depends on toplink. So if I have to keep on adding all transitive dependencies I guess my pom would be really too big and it defeats the purpose of having maven?